# Render a portion of the dom in nativescript

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript, I am trying to render an *ngFor section of the DOM based on the result set from a Tap event that calls a REST method.  I want the *ngFor to display following the button/tap on the same view that the button is on.  I've scoured the net this entire day and cannot figure this out. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If I understood right, you will have to use `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically inject a component into a specific container at runtime.

Comment: I did a bunch of research, and a few tutorials on ComponentFactoryResolver, but they don't seem to quite reach what I'm trying to achieve. The one important part is that I need the partial UI to load ONLY after the api call has completed returning data.

1. User navigates to the view.
2. User clicks button (GetData for example)
3. Api returns data and the UI display the list of data on the same view

This type of behvior was/is trivial using traditional web development with JQuery/ajax, html/css etc..  Seems it should be just as easy with NativeScript